# Correct use of Sqlite on Android (SQLiteOpenHelper, connections, main thread, etc...)

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm searching info about SQLite on Android, and read some chapters of some books on Android Programming, but I don't know how to really use SQLite on Android correctly.

I'm developing an app that has Activities, Services and BroadcastReceivers, and all of them must read and write data in the database. So I have some questions:

- Where is the best place to create the `SQLiteOpenHelper` instance? I read about this, and it seems that the best way is to have only `SQLiteOpenHelper` for all the app.
- When, and where, do I need to get `SQLiteDatabase` object by calling `dbHelper.getReadableDatabase()` (or `getWritableDatabase`)? I need to do it on each query, closing it after each query?
- I read that I should never do database operations in the main thread, so I'm creating an Async task for each database operation I do in an Activity, is this the best way?

Comment: Thanks for your negative votes ¬¬

Comment: best place to create SQLiteOpenHelper instance is in `ContentProvider`'s `onCreate` method... best place for using `getWritableDatabase()` is in `delete`/`insert`/`update` methods of `ContentProvider` and `getReadableDatabase()`  in `query` ... you don't need to close those databases ... for avoid of using database operation on UI you can use `Loaders` with CP ... i know that writing CP is pain in the a** but with well written CP you avoid many problems (such as accessing database from multiple theread)

Comment: Thanks Selvin. I would like to use SQLite without using a ContentProvider, because I don't need to share any data with other apps. I readed that I don't need a content provider in my app: http://touchlabblog.tumblr.com/post/32793099735/training-sqlite#_=_. There is no way to use SQLite correctly without using a ContentProvider?

Comment: but why you don't wanna use CP ... for such cases (multiple application component (Activity, Ser, BR)) using CP has another added value ... if you fx insert something in service your Activity with fx ListView will get informed about this and reload items ... anyway you can try to put db access methods in custom Application class

Comment: Ok Selvin, I'll take a look at CP. If using it will make my app working correctly, I'll use it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most of the question is rather subjective. But let me take a stab at it

> Where is the best place to create the SQLiteOpenHelper instance? I
>   readed about this, and seems that the best way is to have only
>   SQLiteOpenHelper for all the app.

You can create a *Class* in your project that extends `SQLiteOpenHelper`. This is helpful when you would be accessing the same *Database* in multiple `Activities` in your application.

> When, and where, do I need to get SQLiteDatabase object by calling
>   dbHelper.getReadableDatabase() (or getWritableDatabase)? I need to do
>   it on each query, closing it after each query?

This would be done in the *Class* that extends *SQLiteOpenHelper*. For example: (*this is an excerpt from a Vogella article provided at the end of this post*)

```
public void open() throws SQLException {
    database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}
```

And in an Activity that will use the Class:

```
CommentsDataSource datasource = new CommentsDataSource(this);
datasource.open();
```

And a `Cursor` and the `Database` *connection* made from the `Activity` should be closed when you are done with fetching, modifying, adding, etc with the `Database`.

*The code above will make sense when you have read the webpage linked later.*

> I readed that I should never do database operations in the main
>   thread, so I'm creating an Async task for each database operation I do
>   in an Activity, this is the best way?

Ideally, yes. I would personally recommend using an *Asynctask* especially when you would be dealing with large record sets.

Finally, I would suggest that you read up on this tutorial by Lars Vogella: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html. It will address most of your concerns and queries. Good luck. :-)

Comment: Thanks IceMAN! Your answer and Vogella's article helped me a lot!

Comment: @SergioViudes: You are welcome. He also has other good tutorials that I _still_ find very helpful. I am sure you will too. :-)

Answer (score 0):

**1.Where is the best place to create the SQLiteOpenHelper instance?**

SQLiteOpenHelper helps you to connect with the tables you defined using it.So you can define all of your tables in one SQLiteOpenHelper class.

**2.When, and where, do I need to get SQLiteDatabase object by calling dbHelper.getReadableDatabase() (or getWritableDatabase)?**

Whenever you want to write data in your defined tables you will need to call **getWritableDatabase** and for reading from them you will need **getReadableDatabase**

You can make CRUD(Create, Retrieve, Update, Delete) functions for these purposes.

3.**Never do database operations in the main thread!**

I'm not sure about this one.

well here's a link for you to start on with SQLite-
http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. About SQLiteOpenHelper, I know what it is, in fact, I did it, and my app is working with my SQLite database, but I needed to create more than one SQLiteOpenHelper because using only one to access database from different threads cased my app to fail. I readed that I should create only 1 (http://touchlabblog.tumblr.com/post/32793099735/training-sqlite#_=_), so I don't need exactly how to handle it.

About getReadableDatabase/getWritableDatabase, I'm doing like your tutorial: open connection -> query -> close connection.